# armhf toolchain on Debian Wheezy to compile Beaglebone Black kernel

Tags: debian, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I am trying to build the Linux kernel for the beaglebone black (which uses armhf) on a Debian Wheezy (amd64) VM. However, I need to get a armhf version of the gcc and other tools.

From what I can understand on multiple forums and blogs, the emdebian chain that used to be previously used to get a cross-compiler is no longer supported and MultiArch is the way ahead. I want to use MultiArch since I will need to do the build multiple times for the next couple of years.

So a few questions:

1. How do I get a working version of armhf gcc on debian wheezy?
   I tried:

   ```
   dpkg --add-architecture armhf
   sudo apt-get install gcc:armhf
   ```

   but this fails due to being unable to resolve dependencies (APT version 0.9.7.9 (amd64) & dpkg version 1.16.15 (amd64) both claim multiple architecture support). All I get is

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
   or been moved out of Incoming.
   The following information may help to resolve the situation:

   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    gcc:armhf : Depends: cpp:armhf (>= 4:4.6.3-8) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: gcc-4.6:armhf (>= 4.4.7-1~) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

   doing `sudo apt-get build-dep armhf gcc` does not help either since the dependencies themselves have other dependencies which apt-get cannot resolve recursively.
2. What other armhf specific tools might be required for the kernel build. And how would I get them?
3. Is there an easy way out of this?

Comment: If you need a toolchain only for the kernel, you're better off with [Buildroot](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_cross_compilation_toolchain). You can either use this toolchain for your kernel externally or compile the kernel within BR.

Comment: Have you tried this: `apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf`?

Comment: yegorich: Debian Wheezy does not have any of those packages in its repos.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this toolchain comes from emdebian's repos.

Comment: I also tried adding the emdebian repo by adding `deb http://www.emdebian.org/debian squeeze main` to sources.list, but apt-get gives a 404 error when i try to update it

Comment: For all practical purposes the emdebian toolchain seems to have disappeared completely. Any other options of getting it to work?

Comment: Any suggestions? Embedian is gone and multiarch isn't ready yet. What do people currently use?

Comment: Try to ask your question on [debian-embedded](https://lists.debian.org/debian-embedded/) mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Wheezy has unfortunately been poorly supported for cross-toolchains due to manpower shortage and us assuming multiarch crosstoolchains would be ready sooner so the old toolchains stopped being maintained too early. Sorry about that.

Emdebian.org is now back after an outage. So the existing lenny and squeeze crosstoolchains are available again, as are new multiarch-built cross-toolchains for jessie. For unstable there are cross-toolchains in unstable now.

But Wheezy is still a gap. I tried rebuilding some toolchains for wheezy (with buildcross) and hit problems. If someone wanted to work on fixing that then emdebian would be happy to host them.

This is the definitive page for info: https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains

Comment: Are there any good workarounds for wheezy which won't have me install every dependency manually/break the system?